# Migration ASP.NET Core 6.0 to 7.0

Tags: automapper, automapper-7, asp.net-core-7.0

Project works fine in ASP.NET Core 6.0 but when I tried to migrate it to 7.0, it builds successfully without errors but at runtime I got this error:

> Message   "GenericArguments[0], 'AbilityFix.Model.Models.Forums', on 'T MaxIntegerT' violates the constraint of type 'T'." string
>
> - ```
>   InnerException  {"Method System.Linq.Enumerable.MaxInteger: type argument 'AbilityFix.Model.Models.Forums' violates the constraint of type parameter 'T'."}
>   ```
>
> System.Exception {System.Security.VerificationException}

Error in `startup.cs` file

```
 services.AddAutoMapper(mapperConfig => mapperConfig.AddProfiles(GetType().Assembly));
```

[image]

Comment: You need AM 12.

Comment: after updated i got CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Reflection.Assembly' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AutoMapper.Profile>'

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core